# Store word occurrences in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `words`, and in it I'd like to store key/value pairs of words and their occurrences.

I want to make the `count` column an auto-incrementing column, since I want to keep adding words (from a C++ application) and have the `count` increment on its own automatically. However, I figured that the table would be searched a lot, so I made `word` the primary key. I ran into an error, though, saying I cannot set a non-primary key as an auto-incrementing column.

Is there a way to do this properly such that I can insert into the table and have the database handle incrementing and all that?

Comment: It seems to me that you're mixing autoincrement column attribute with incrementing the value by issuing an UPDATE.

Comment: Your description does not make any sense.  Auto-increment columns used for identity generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table to store the words. The `word` column is the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `word` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   PRIMARY KEY (`word`)
);
```

Then insert your words in the table like this:

```
INSERT INTO `words`(word) VALUES('car') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;
INSERT INTO `words`(word) VALUES('plane') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;
INSERT INTO `words`(word) VALUES('car') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;
```

If the word doesn't exist in the table, `nb` defaults to `1` (this is in the table definition).
If the word already exist in the table, the value of `nb` for this word is increased by 1.

After the 3 inserts above, the table contains:

```
word  | count  
car   | 2
plane | 1
```

You may need to adjust:
- the length of the column `word`
- the character set and collation

Documentation: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the auto increment column as the primary key, and add an additional index containing the `word` column only. if you're searching by word, this index will be used